# Why can I update/create references objects whe the id does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 tables with references id. And I can update/create department when the id does not exist. I think that I tied my id badly. But what I did wrong, I don't know. Please explain what I did wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE FACULTY (
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,  
NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL );


CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (   
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,   
NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,   
FACULTY_ID INTEGER REFERENCES FACULTY(ID) ON DELETE SET NULL );
```

Faculty table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Faculty")
public class Faculty implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

   // getters and setters of name
```

Department table

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "department") 
public class Department implements Serializable {

        private Long id;
        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        private Faculty facultyId;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "faculty_id")
        public Faculty getFacultyId() {
            return facultyId;
        }

        public void setFacultyId(Faculty facultyId) {
            this.facultyId = facultyId;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

       // getters and setters of name
```

Comment: The id is automatically generated on a create

Answer (score 0):

According to OneToMany relationship, one department can have many faculties.

Thus, in your relationship, `faculty` table will have reference to `departmentID`. In your case, if `dept` will have `facultyId` as reference then there will be multiple values for that ID as there are many faculties in 1 department.

So, keep `departmentID` as reference in `Faculty` table. This way 1 faculty will have 1 departmentID.

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (   
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,   
NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,   
); 



CREATE TABLE FACULTY (
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,  
NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
DEPARTMENT_ID INTEGER REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID) ON DELETE SET NULL );
```

Comment: hope this helps for you :)